# How do you pass information through app store to app during initial install?

Tags: mobile, app-store

I have a mobile app that generically supports multiple customers. I want to link to our app in the app store (or marketplace) and pass which customer should be defaulted during the install.  Is this possible?

For example:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/consume-mobile-isp-packages/id337064413?mt=8&customer=XYZ
```

So that when the user installs the app it will load with XYZ as the default customer.

**1. How should this link be formatted?**

**2. How do I access this value from code?**

Cheers!